# How would I go about searching a URL's contents for a word?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How would I use JavaScript or PHP to check if a URL entered into a HTML input contains words given in a table/array?

I've tried to look for other pages including how to do it, but they all just search the document the user is on, or search the URL for a word.

Deleted all my code ;(

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are wanting to do? And of course you need to show some code for what you have tried.

Comment: You can use `cURL` in PHP or `AJAX` through JavaScript to `GET` the contents of a webpage / URL, and then simply `parse` the `response`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way you can do it by using ES6 `.includes()`;

```js
function findWords() {
  var url = document.getElementById("input").value;

  var words = ["stack", "please", "help"];

  for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (url.includes(words[i])) {
      console.log("Url contains " + words[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input" />
<button id="btn" onclick="findWords()">Find Words</button>
```

If you were to put `www.stackoverflow.com/questions` into the input box it would find the word `stack` exists from the array of words.

You can read more about `.includes()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp).